# SQL Server query result needs to give different values in two columns of the same name from the same source table

Tags: sql-server, left-join

Not sure if my title makes sense but here's what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to write a query that produces the same column twice in the result but the first column will have different values than the second column.

For example, in short, Table provider_mstr contains the columns national_provider_id, provider_id, and description.  Table appointments contains the columns person_id and rendering_provider_id. Table person contains the columns primarycare_prov_name and primarycare_prov_id. So I'm looking for the result to look like this:

```
**primarycare_prov_name**     **national_provider_ip**     **description**     **national_provider_id**
     John Doe                        12345                    Rick Smith            56789
     Jane Doe                        25832                    Barb Johnson          82473
...
```

So I'm wanting the national_provider_id for the primarycare_prov_name in the first national_provider_id column but the national_provider_id of the rendering_provider_id (description) in the second national_provider_id column.

Here is my full code:

```
select 
person.person_nbr,
person.first_name,
person.middle_name,
person.last_name,
person.date_of_birth,
person.sex,
person.email_address,
person.address_line_1,
person.address_line_2,
person.city,
person.state,
person.zip,
person.home_phone,
person.day_phone,
person.alt_phone,
person.primarycare_prov_name,
provider_mstr.national_provider_id,
appointments.appt_date,
appointments.begintime,
appointments.appt_type,
appointments.appt_nbr,
appointments.details,
appointments.rendering_provider_id,
location_mstr.location_name,
provider_mstr.description,
provider_mstr.national_provider_id,
charges.cpt4_code_id
FROM person
LEFT JOIN patient
ON person.person_id=patient.person_id
LEFT JOIN appointments
ON person.person_id=appointments.person_id
LEFT JOIN location_mstr
ON appointments.location_id=location_mstr.location_id
LEFT JOIN provider_mstr
ON person.primarycare_prov_id = provider_mstr.provider_id
LEFT JOIN charges
ON person.person_id = charges.person_id
WHERE .....
```

So what do I need to do to get that to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join to the provider_mstr table twice. Once for rendering provider second time for primary care provider:

```
SELECT
  person.primarycare_prov_name,
  primarycare_provider.national_provider_id,
  rendering_provider.description,
  rendering_provider.national_provider_id
FROM person
LEFT JOIN appointments 
  ON person.person_id=appointments.person_id
LEFT JOIN provider_mstr rendering_provider 
  ON rendering_provider.provider_id = appointment.rendering_provider_id
LEFT JOIN provider_mstr primarycare_provider 
  ON primarycare_provider.provider_id = person.primarycare_prov_id
```